# Using forward proxy without configuring proxy server in the client but instead use route table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy

I am currently trying to figure out whether a forward proxy in a EC2 instance can capture the traffic coming from the client that does not specifically configure any proxy server configuration, but only use route table to point to the forward proxy ENI instead.

Here is how it looks like:
[image]
The security group of each instance already allows any inbound traffic from the VPC CIDR block.

I've tried to access a public IP from the EC2 Application instance, but it seems the HAProxy does not capture anything.

But when I specifically configure the EC2 Application instance to use a proxy server with the IP address of the HAProxy, it'll worked.

My question is: Is it possible for the forward proxy instance to capture the traffic coming from the client (EC2 Application) that does not specifically configure any proxy server configuration, but only use route table instead to direct any public IP traffic to the forward proxy ENI?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done.

1. Remove any existing Internet Gateway or NAT Gateway.
2. Configure the proxy as the default route.
3. Turn off "source / destination check" on the EC2 instance running the proxy.

Your proxy will now be responsible for correctly forwarding traffic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am I understanding it correct that I have to setup the HAProxy as transparent proxy? Do you know any online examples or guides that I can refer?